# implementing a play again feature in a random number guess generator

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have been doing some programming exercises in university lately and i came across one that wanted the user to guess between the numbers 1 and 100. They also want it to have the ability to let the user play again. When first ran the program is fine but when i say 'y' to play again it generates the same number i previously guessed:

[image: 1]

I found some solutions however there was so much spaghetti code i couldn't read it on websites. is there any way to save a few lines of code.

here is my source:

```
    int guess = 0;
        Random r1 = new Random();
        int answer = r1.Next(1, 100);
        bool finished = false;
        while (!finished)
        {
          
          
            Console.WriteLine("please guess a number between 1 - 100");
            guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (guess < answer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("your answer is too low please try again!");
                }
                else if (guess > answer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("your answer is too high please try again!");
                
                }
           else if (guess == answer)//nested 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("your answer is correct!");
                Console.WriteLine("answer:" + answer);
                Console.WriteLine("Play again? ('y' or 'n')");
                string playAgain = null;
                playAgain = Console.ReadLine();

                if (playAgain == "n")
                {
                    finished = true;
                }
            }//end of nested else 

        }//end of while
```

Comment: You never call `Random.Next` inside the loop so you end up using the same value on every iteration. Move the variable declarations *inside* the loop, preferably in the line where they're assigned. Declaring variables at the top of the method is a great way to widen their scope and introduce bugs

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the same number is being given every time to guess is that you do not generate it if the user wants to continue the game, but instead you use what was already declared.

```
else if (guess == answer)//nested 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("your answer is correct!");
            Console.WriteLine("answer:" + answer);
            Console.WriteLine("Play again? ('y' or 'n')");
            string playAgain = null;
            playAgain = Console.ReadLine();

            if (playAgain == "n")
            {
                finished = true;
            }
            answer = r1.Next(1,100);
        }//end of nested else
```

If you want to get rid of some lines, then you can simply declare some variable inside of the loop.

```
    Random r1 = new Random();
    int answer = r1.Next(1, 100);
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("please guess a number between 1 - 100");
        guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (guess < answer)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("your answer is too low please try again!");
        }
        else if (guess > answer)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("your answer is too high please try again!");
            
        }
       else if (guess == answer)//nested 
       {
           Console.WriteLine("your answer is correct!");
           Console.WriteLine("answer:" + answer);
           Console.WriteLine("Play again? ('y' or 'n')");

            if (Console.ReadLine() == "n")
            {
                break; // stop the loop
            }
        }//end of nested else 

    }//end of while
```

Answer (score 0):

Because before restarting the guess, the field "answer" is always the previously generated random value "54". Therefore, if the user enters "y", you can add a statement to reset the value of "answer".

```
// code omitted
// ...
// reset answer
if(playAgain == "y")
{
    answer = r1.Next(1, 100);
}

if (playAgain == "n")
{
    finished = true;
}
```